# Updating Instance monitoring using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, autoscaling, launch-configuration

I am trying to update instance monitoring using the AWS CLI for autoscaling and using the documentation [on AWS here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/as-instance-monitoring.html#enable-as-instance-metrics)
I am trying the below command and have found no success or further documentation.

```
>> aws autoscaling update-auto-scaling-group --auto-scaling-group-name awseb-e-test-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-5ECR3Tc0de  --instance-monitoring Enabled=true

usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:
  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
Unknown options: --instance-monitoring, Enabled=true
```

I've also tried `aws autoscaling update-auto-scaling-group --auto-scaling-group-name awseb-e-test-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-5ECR3Tc0de  --instance-monitoring help` but that doesn't offer any insight into the option `--instance-monitoring`

What would be the best way to enable detailed monitoring for instances on an existing launch configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you **cannot** enable detailed monitoring for instances on an existing launch configuration. It is supported only in [create-launch-configuration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/create-launch-configuration.html)

From [Monitoring Your Auto Scaling Groups and Instances Using Amazon CloudWatch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/as-instance-monitoring.html):

> If you have an Auto Scaling group and need to change which type of
>   monitoring is enabled for your Auto Scaling instances, you must create
>   a new launch configuration and update the Auto Scaling group to use
>   this launch configuration.

After you update the AS group with the new launch configuration:

> From now on, the instances that the Auto Scaling group launches will
>   use the updated monitoring type. However, if you have existing
>   instances in the Auto Scaling group, they maintain the previous
>   monitoring type. You can terminate these instances so that Auto
>   Scaling replaces them, or update each instance individually.

Comment: Thanks. Creating a copy of the launch config with monitoring enabled and attaching it to the AS group did it.